# Displaying Large Amounts of Data in an HTML Table

Tags: html, css

I am generating HTML tables based on SQL statements for a Datawarehouse created through meta table information.

One of the issues I have is some of returned Datatables have 100 plus columns. Is there a neat way of displaying this in an HTML table or a specific design solution. Please note I am looking at the display here. Changing the amount of columns available is not an option. All columns need to be rendered.

Many thanks in advance for input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can think of 2 good solutions:

1. Wrap the whole table with a fixed-width container, and set `overflow-x: auto` on it. That will cause the table to scroll.
2. Allow the user to filter out whichever columns he doesn't need to see using JavaScript/jQuery.

Both are possible, the first is obviously easier to implement, but with the second you have more control. Choose your path and if you're stuck, you can ask here on StackOverflow for help.

Comment: I did 1 (with just `overflow:auto`) and 2 in a custom dropdownlist overload. It worked out really nicely.

Comment: Im thinking of using a table with a couple of fixed columns (etc. when you scroll left and right some left columns dont move) and the headers remain intact. Any example you guys might know of?

Comment: @Jonathan: I've asked this question once. Very hard to pull off. Never actually succeeded with it myself.

Comment: Heres an example although doesnt look ve good. http://acatalept.com/common/test/fixed-table.html

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is called datagrid. You definitely should not generate the HTML yourself(as you sad) and instead just bind the result set to any kind of server-side data-grid or use some kind of client-side jQuery datagrid implementation.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations

Comment: Thanks for the link. These grids dont meet my requirements as they simply display information. I prefer using HTML as I have complete control of the outcome. I have used jQgrid previously but wasnt really that impressed (well for my needs) I also dont like the idea of someone new having to learn the technology. I +1 your answer.